# Updating subscriber via Ruby Library for CreateSend API

Tags: ruby, campaign-monitor, createsend

I could be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to update an existing subscriber name in a CreateSend client list using Ruby.

All list details are correct, here's what I have (subscriber already exists in the list):

```
@subscriber = CreateSend::Subscriber.get(
    {:api_key => ENV['CM_API_KEY']}, ENV['CM_LIST_ID'], "me@me.com"
)
```

According to the tests the update() method should have 4 params:

```
@subscriber.update("me@me.com", "Name of Person", [], true)
```

Calling this results in an ArgumentError error: **wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)**.

So, I try calling update by passing in a hash of the updated attributes:

```
@subscriber.update({"Name" => "New Name"})
```

No errors occur and the returned @subscriber object contains all the updated fields until you reload it from the API - it's back to the original state.

Reference to the test code:

- https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-ruby/blob/master/test/subscriber_test.rb#L51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this if anyone else experiences the same issue.

`CreateSend::Subscriber.get` returns an instance of the `Hashie class`, where the `update` methods expects one parameter containing a hash. This does not actually update the subscriber details, but only the attributes of the local Hashie instance variable.

`CreateSend::Subscriber.new` will return an instance of the Subscriber class where the `update` method expects 4 parameters. Calling the update method in this instance will actually perform the update correctly.